# Escape quote in HQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm developping an application with spring mvc and hibernate, i have a problem in my hql query when i want to select an object from the database by his name.

Because the name contain a quote (ingénieur d'étude)

```
String hql = "From Intervenant I Where I.profil like '"+profil+"'";
```

i had this exception :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting ''', found '<EOF>' [From com.model.Intervenant I Where I.profil like 'Ingénieur d'étude']
```

Is the user who inserts datas, so how I can know what the user inserted and where it has put the quote or any other special caracters ?

Please can you help me !

Answer (score 3):

Put single quote to escaping charater in mysql like following

```
profile = ingénieur d''étude;
```

OR

```
profile = ingénieur d\'étude;
```

Comment: But is the user who inserts datas, so how I can know what the user inserted and where it has put the quote or any other special caracters ?

Comment: You have to code in your framework to escape this type of character If do not this then also may SQL injection problem