# How to use Single Quote with ESCAPE in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008, hql, hibernate-criteria

Please help me to understand what this below SQL server query will do

```
SELECT * from emp e where e.empName like '%'' escape ''%'
```

My next immediate question - How to achieve the same in `HQL`, Is that i can use escape in `HQL`?

Comment: What do you think that query will do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `WHERE name LIKE '%O''Brien%';`? If so, why do you need the `ESCAPE` keyword? Just double-up the single quotes in the value - or, if HQL is professional enough to support proper, strongly-typed parameters, you shouldn't even need to worry about it...

Comment: I m in need to escape the single Quotes as a value , To ignore the single Quote if it is in String

Answer (score 0):

This query return all records of table `emp` with contains `'escape'` in the `empName` field.

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern

Look [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) link.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

It will return everything from the `emp` table where the `empName` column contains a value that has `'' escape ''` in it somewhere.

```
select 1 where 'this string contains '' escape '' in it' like '%'' escape ''%'
```

This is quite weird because of the double quotes in your search parameter... but this is because **the quotes within the string have to be escaped with a single quote**.

Consider this example for something similar.

```
select 1 where 'John Smith' like '%Sm%'
```

This is looking for the letters `Sm` in the string `John Smith`

Escaping single quotes is the same for `HQL` for what [I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607972/escape-quote-in-hql-query)